# setValue from material UI select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

I have created a dropdown menu

```
  const [splittingMethod, setSplittingMethod] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    //setSplittingMethod(e)
    console.log('value', splittingMethod)

  }
....

  <FormControl variant="filled" >
            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-filled-label" className={classes.field}>Splitting Method</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="demo-simple-select-filled-label"
              id="demo-simple-select-filled"
              value={splittingMethod}
              onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)}
            >
              <MenuItem value="random">
                Random
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={'timeEnd'}>Time End</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={'slidingWindow'}>Sliding Window</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
```

and I want to save the selected item's value into the `splittingMethod` variable. How can I achieve this? My current method would give me an error:

```
react-dom.development.js:13231 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access `e.target.value` to get the value

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FormControl, InputLabel, Select, MenuItem } from "@material-ui/core";
const App = () => {
  const [splittingMethod, setSplittingMethod] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<{
      name?: string | undefined;
      value: unknown;
    }>
  ) => {
    // type checking
    const value = typeof e.target.value === "string" ? e.target.value : "";

    setSplittingMethod(value);
  };
  return (
    <FormControl variant="filled" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <InputLabel
        id="demo-simple-select-filled-label"
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
      >
        Splitting Method
      </InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="demo-simple-select-filled-label"
        id="demo-simple-select-filled"
        value={splittingMethod}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <MenuItem value="random">Random</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={"timeEnd"}>Time End</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={"slidingWindow"}>Sliding Window</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default App;
```

### Live demo

[image: Edit setvalue-from-material-ui-select]